# SIP CANCEL request never gets 200 Canceling response

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, sip

I'm sending SIP requests to Twilio SIP Trunk, using Node.js and Kirm/Sip module, I'm trying to cancel the call after receiving '180 Ringing' response.

The problem is that the [CANCEL] SIP request is sent but the server never replies with status '200 Canceling' like it should, instead it replies with a TCP [ACK] and the call remains ringing..

The Cancel request is a copy from the Invite request but changed the Method and CSec Method.

**INVITE request:**

```
INVITE sip:123456789@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com SIP/2.0
From:  <sip:test@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com>;tag=168502
To:  <sip:123456789@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com>
Call-ID: 284466
CSeq: 969240 INVITE
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact:  <sip:test@192.168.61.4>
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.61.4:61244;branch=z9hG4bK847573
Content-Length: 363
Proxy-Authorization: Digest realm="sip.twilio.com",username="test",nonce="XXXX",uri="sip:123456789@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com",nc=00000001,cnonce="XXXXXXX",qop=auth,opaque="XXXXXXX",response="XXXXXXX"

v=0
o=- 3700480907 3700480907 IN IP4 192.168.61.4
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4012 RTP/AVP 123 8 0 101
c=IN IP4 192.168.61.4
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4013 IN IP4 192.168.61.4
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:123 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:123 maxplaybackrate=16000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
```

**CANCEL request:**

```
CANCEL sip:123456789@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com SIP/2.0
CSeq: 969240 CANCEL
Call-ID: 284466
From:  <sip:test@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com>;tag=168502
To:  <sip:123456789@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.61.4:61244;branch=z9hG4bK847573
Content-Length: 0
```

So any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your CANCEL looks perfectly valid. Is this the actual message. I assume there is no route header in INVITE. If it is in actual INVITE then copy to CANCEL also.

Answer (score 2):

When receiving 180 Ringing To-tag should be set. 
Look for it in 180 Ringing To header.
Something like "To: ;tag=9273782374" is expected.

You need to match CANCEL request with INVITE transaction so To tag should be set in CANCEL request.

```
CANCEL sip:123456789@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com SIP/2.0
CSeq: 969240 CANCEL
Call-ID: 284466
From:  <sip:test@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com>;tag=168502
To:  <sip:123456789@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com>;tag=missingToTag
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.61.4:61244;branch=z9hG4bK847573
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply,

I have copied the Tag from Ringing response, now To looks like this:

`To:  <sip:123456789@sample.pstn.ie1.twilio.com>;tag=09200453_6772d868_d8b44d32-4e1b-4175-ace9-487bbf2a27f6`

But still doesn't get the Cancelling response

Comment: I am sorry. To tag answer looks bad. I feel like the CANCEL request You sent was OK. The issue must be somewhere else.

Please look at page 52 of rfc : https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while and just solved it when I saw this post.

You have to make sure that the tag from the "To:" field is the tag that is returned *after* the ACK to the invite request.

Flow goes like this:

[image: Screenshot from Wireshark showing the SIP requests]